# Set maxAge for express at router/controller level

Tags: node.js, caching, express, routes, cache-control

I would like all routes defined by a express router to have a different `max-age` than assets middleware.

For express static middleware I set `max-age` header for all requests using.

```
app.use(express.static('public', { maxAge: '1d' }));
```

I tried to set this at app level:

```
express.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=86400');
  return next();
});
```

Although this works for all routes it will also overwrite the `max-age` for static middleware.

Comment: how are you checking? 1d is converted to 86400 anyway. Also order of middlewares matters, so the static middleware should be defined first.

Comment: That was the problem @hassansin, I was defining the static middleware after setting the header. Thank you! Would you mind to post it as an answer so I can give you the credits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the static middleware is defined after the middleware that sets the `cache-control` header. Since **`serve-static` module doesn't overwrite the header if it already exists**, the `maxAge` value for static files is not reflected in the header.

To fix this, the **static middleware can be moved before the other middleware**. As a result, the other middleware will never be reached for static files.